# Why does updating Ubuntu reset my boot order? Can I change this?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I dual boot Windows and Ubuntu. Since I use Windows most often and just use Ubuntu to do development I'd like my computer to boot into Windows by default and only Ubuntu when I choose to. This works fine normally. However, invariably after I do a software update in Ubuntu, the boot order gets reset to Ubuntu first and Windows second. This isn't a huge deal, and is only a slight annoyance adding approx 1 min. to my boot time. Mainly, I just don't understand why or how Ubuntu does this. Every time it happens I go set the boot order in the BIOS and after and Ubuntu update the order resets back to Ubuntu on top.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu does this because it assumes you're installing it because you want to use it, so it makes it easy to boot.  If you want to change the default, find this line in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
set default=0
```

and change it to

```
set default=1
```

Assuming that Windows is the second option in your grub menu.  If it's not, then replace `1` with `[x-1]` if x is Windows's place in the grub menu.

Comment: Did not work. Ubuntu reset the boot order again

Comment: Can you post a copy of your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file?